# How to add overlay color to chart.js pie chart segment?

Tags: javascript, php, charts, chart.js

I'm using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to draw charts on my web page.

I'm successfully able to draw pie chart by below codes:

```
var dataPiChart = [
            {
                value: 350,
                color:"#F7464A",
                highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                label: "PHP"
            },
            {
                value: 100,
                color: "#46BFBD",
                highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                label: "JavaScript"
            },
            {
                value: 500,
                color: "#FDB45C",
                highlight: "#FFC870",
                label: "HTML"
            }
        ];

new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d")).Pie(dataPiChart, {
                legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"
            });
```

NOTE: Here `canvas` is my canvas id. It's working fine the way I want it. Now I have a value for each dataset which is the % complete value for ex: `PHP - 20%, JavaScript- 30%, HTML - 20%`. Now I want to make 20% of PHP segment in deep color and 80% which is not complete in fade color. Some how to distinguish how much % complete.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new canvas object and position it under the actual chart. This new chart has the split data values. Make sure that the datapoints in your original chart that are split have a transparent background so that the underlying splits show through.

---

**Preview**

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="splitContainer">
  <canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="800"></canvas>
  <canvas class="canvasSplit" id="canvas2" height="300" width="800"></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.splitContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.canvasSplit {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**Script**

```
var dataPiChart2 = [
  {
    value: 200,
    color:"rgba(247, 70, 74, 0.6)",
    label: "PHP1"
  },
  {
    value: 150,
    color:"rgba(247, 70, 74, 0.2)",
    label: "PHP2"
  },
  // values that are not split remain as is
  {
    value: 100,
    color: "#46BFBD",
    label: "JavaScript"
  },
  {
    value: 500,
    color: "#FDB45C",
    label: "HTML"
  }
];

new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas2').getContext("2d")).Pie(dataPiChart2, {
  segmentShowStroke: false
});

var dataPiChart = [
  {
    value: 350,
    // transparent show the split shows through
    color:"rgba(247, 70, 74, 0.2)",
    highlight: "rgba(247, 70, 74, 0.7)",
    label: "PHP"
  },
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ww8qpdvw/

Comment: Looks good. Thanks for your input. But how can I show some kind of tooltip or value in chart itself so that user comes to know how much value is done and how much is pending?

Comment: You can position the split chart over the other chart then.